# Merge libvirt and libvirtd tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Shouldn't [libvirt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libvirt) and [libvirtd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libvirtd) tags be merged?

Comment: This was brought up again today. I've created a synonym between the two and am prepared to merge them. Merging: "retags all questions tagged with another tag – which is not automatically done when a synonym is created. As merging is not (easily) reversible, it should be done with caution".  As the question and the top answer both specifically used the word "merge", I'll proceed with the merge in a few days, barring objections.

Comment: The tags have been merged.

Answer (score 12):

I can't see a difference in the type of questions that have one tag or the other. People seem to indifferently use one or the other.

Since the `libvirt` library and the `libvirtd` daemon interact with each other, and there is no alternative implementation of either as far as I know, very few issues involve only the library or only the daemon. Furthermore, “libvirt” is also the name of the project as a whole, including both the library and the daemon.

Therefore I think the tags should be merged.

If anyone thinks the tags should remain separate, please:

- Explain when one should use one or the other.
- Explain how this matches current usage. If it doesn't, explain how to avoid having too many people use the wrong tag in the future.

If you think that some questions about some aspect of libvirt should use different tags, then different tag names may be in order.

Comment: A year later, these tags have not been merged. I've created synonyms today and am prepared to merge them. Please reply here if you've changed your mind for any reason; I'll revisit the issue in a week. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller I still don't see any reason to keep separate tags. By the way, [there are plenty of tag synonym proposals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags) (but watch out, [tag:historical-unix] is not at all a synonym of [tag:history], I have no idea why people voted for that one).

Answer (score 7):

Writing an Answer to put this post into the Active Question list of Meta.

I've created a synonym between the two and am prepared to merge them. Merging: "retags all questions tagged with another tag – which is not automatically done when a synonym is created. As merging is not (easily) reversible, it should be done with caution". As the question and the top answer both specifically used the word "merge", I'll proceed with the merge in a few days, barring objections.

Comment: A tag edit would have been sufficient to bump into the active list. ([Tag:status-completed]?)

Comment: I think writing an Answer is the correct approach here. An answer provides the means to clearly highlight the irreversibility of going ahead with a merge -- so users have a chance to put forward any potential objections before the task is completed.

Comment: Since this wasn't a fresh or highly-voted topic, I thought I'd take the slow route.  Status-completed is premature at this point, since I wanted to confirm the community's consensus. I'll do like I said and follow up in a few days, to give people time to see this.

Answer (score -4):

libvirt is an API, libvirtd is a daemon that can be used by the libvirt API? not sure, but I would say no.

Comment: And why would you say no? In any case, calling libvirt an “API” is misleading: AFAIK there's a single implementation of that interface, which is the library also called libvirt. In any case, libvirt is also the name of the project as a whole, including the libvirt library and the libvirtd program.

Comment: This would make sense if we allowed questions on both and considered the use of separate tags useful for searching or following. But... Questions about the API would probably be off-topic here (only standard POSIX API is on-topic, everything else would go to SO). So this distinction won't matter.